# Facing Error in GData as 'Undefined symbols for architecture i386'

Tags: ios, linker-errors, gdata

I am using`GData` to fetch email contacts from the user.while Running my code am getting these ERRORS.

OtherLinkerFlags : `-lxml2`, `-ObjC`, `-all_load`..

--
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

`"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataQueryContact", referenced from:`

objc-class-ref in VController.o

`"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleContact", referenced from:`

objc-class-ref in VController.o

`"_kGDataServiceDefaultUser", referenced from:`

-[VController getEmailContact] in VController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anybody help me to find what wrong have i done. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you include all the required libaries to the project and the related target?

Comment: yes.CoreData, Security, CFNetwork, CoreTelephony, MobileCoreServices, StoreKit, SysstemConfiguration, libSQLite3, MessageUI, AddressBookUI, Quartzcore, libz, libz1.2.5,libxml2, libxml2.2, GData Headers, libGdataTouchStatic. in my Project.

Comment: In the navigation tree go to your top left item, which is the project folder. Then go to our target. (To each of them if there are more than one) Then go to "Build Phases". Then open "Link Binary With Libraries". There double check if all of the libraries you need are included in that list.

Comment: hwy @GreyCode have you found any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the ".h" instead of the ".m", I think your problem is just a typing mistake.

Comment: import .h files ? where ? like Header files or some other?

Comment: in Code i have imported .h files. like '#import "GData.h"'.are you mentioning this?

Comment: at the top of your `VController.h`, make sure all your `#import` statements are like `#import "header.h"` & non is like `#import "header.m"`

Comment: yep, thats what i have mentioned.

Comment: Header Search Paths: /usr/include/libxml2. is this ok ? have i done anyother mistake? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try using `${SRCROOT}/usr/include/libxml2` instead